# Android ImageButton Centered Responsive Width

Tags: android, width, imagebutton, percentage

I would like the have only one ImageButton centered horizontally and vertically, but with a responsive width of a specific percentage, let's say 70%, and its height according to its width (so it won't be stretched)

I did so far the centering and I'm trying to achieve the responsive width.

This is the code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#30CCA4">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".30"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_image"
    android:background="@null" />
```

How can I do the responsive width?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_bt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF4081" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code :

```
ImageButton    img_bt = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.img_bt);
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width/10*7, width/10*7);
    img_bt.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Quang Doan